# Is it possible to negotiate with high salary having an offer letter to another company?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I have 2 years experience. I have an offer letter from one company. In another company(MNC based) I cleared one round. So my question is

1.If i got selected in MNC, is it possible to increase salary as i have an offer letter from one company.Is that a right way to speak about other company offer if salary is very few ratio from offer letter.